# Equivalent of Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler and Zend_Controller_Action_Exception in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

What's the equivalent of Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler and Zend_Controller_Action_Exception in Zend framework 2? I am used to writing an ErrorController in past versions of the framework (eg http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) but now am using version two and I can't find any examples of how you write a custom error handler.

In my instance I am writing a REST server and would like to throw exceptions that correspond to particular HTTP error codes.

From what I can tell, it appears I might need to write my own custom version of Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy which is invoked by Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 does not have something that is really equivalent to the Error Handler with an `ErrorController` in ZF1. I don't recommend trying to implement something similiar in ZF2 (because it works very, very different).

In your case, I would simply use the default `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy`, and then use the view script to differentiate between different error codes and types of requests.

Comment: So unless I add my own try and catch blocks there is no way I can have custom handling of exceptions? After using Silex and ZF1 I am quite used to doing this like "throw new NotFoundHttpException()" and using that to induce a 404.

Comment: Yes, you can. Using the `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy`. Because that will load the configured view script. In which you can set the right headers.

Comment: It really has to do with what you are sending back to the client. So actually, it belongs to the view.